# Mod Rewrite hiding extension conflict

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to figure something out.

This is the code I'm using to hide userpage.php?user=moonwalker and show localhost/moonwalker:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ userpage.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(images|videos|music)/?$ userpage.php?user=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I also use it to load some pages like music, videos or images. Now the problem: I'm trying to hide all .php extensions on my server. For example:
search.php would change to localhost/search

But the script I just posted keeps thinking that search is a username, so it keeps showing me the userpage.php file.

Any idea how to solve this without changing the: localhost/username structure?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

This is the second script I'm using to hide the extensions:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^select/([^/]*)$ /test/PDO/select2.php?lang=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: What about just changing the order?

Comment: @Robert:
Already tried. If I change the order the first script works fine, so it directs me to search/ but the second script doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is not possible. So I just changed my structure. Instead of localhost/username I use now localhost/user/username.

All problems are solved now.